# Image of Sum of Orthogonal Projections

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection

Let $V$ be a finite $d$-dimensional real vector space such that $V = \sum_{i=1}^n V_i$ where the sum is not necessarily direct and each $V_i$ is a linear subspace. In other words, $V$ is spanned by the linear sub-spaces $\{V_i\}_{i=1}^n$.

Show that
$$\text{Im}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\text{proj}_{(V_i)}\right) = V$$
where $\text{proj}_{(V_i)}$ is the orthogonal projection operator on $V_i$ with respect to the Euclidean inner product.

I speculate that induction or dimensionality count would get us the result. Also, note that the statement is equivalent to the kernel of the same operator being zero by symmetry of projection operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $p_i$ the projection onto $V_i$ and by $p$ the sum of all $p_i$'s.

We show that $p$ is injective.

Let $x$ be such that $p(x)=0$. Then for every $j$ we have
$$
0\leq\langle p_j(x),p_j(x)\rangle\leq
\sum_i \langle p_i(x),p_i(x)\rangle=
\sum_i \langle p_i(x),x\rangle=
\langle p(x),x\rangle=0,
$$
so $p_j(x)=0$.  Now, for every $y$ in $V_j$ we have
$$
\langle x,y\rangle =
\langle x,p_j(y)\rangle =
\langle p_j(x),y\rangle =0,
$$
so $x$ is perpendicular to any vector in $V$, hence $x=0$.